# How to get rid of � in the share box of Twitter

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I received some help and figured out how to put the clickable and shareable Twitter button in my Javascript.

However, now when it links the generated quote, in the places where I had unicode escaped characters I get �.

The quotations and hyphen do not appear. How can I fix this?

Below is my Javascript code.

```js
var currentQuote = '';
var quotes = [
'\u201CMeditation is to be aware of every thought and of every feeling, never to say it is right or wrong, but just to watch it and move with it. In that watching, you begin to understand the whole movement of thought and feeling. And out of this awareness comes silence\u201D. -  Jiddu Krishnamurti',
'\u201CHave you not noticed that love is silence? It may be while holding the hand of another, or looking lovingly at a child, or taking in the beauty of an evening. Love has no past or future, and so it is with this extraordinary state of silence.\u201D -  Jiddu Krishnamurti',
'\u201CA quiet mind is all you need. All else will happen rightly, once your mind is quiet. As the sun on rising makes the world active, so does self-awareness affect changes in the mind. In the light of calm and steady self-awareness, inner energies wake up and work miracles without any effort on your part.\u201D -   Nisargadatta Maharaj',
'\u201CLet silence take you to the core of life.\u201D  \u2013 Rumi',
'\u201CSilence is a true friend who never betrays.\u201D \u2013 Confucius',
'\u201CYou throw thorns, falling in my silence they become flowers.\u201D \u2013 Gautama Buddha',
'\u201CSilence is an empty space, space is the home of the awakened mind.\u201D \u2013 Gautama Buddha',
'\u201CCare about what other people think and you will always be their prisoner.\u201D \u2013 Laozi',
'\u201CNot thinking about anything is Zen. Once you know this, walking, sitting, or lying down, everything you do is Zen.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
'\u201CIf you use your mind to study reality, you won\u2019t understand either your mind or reality. If you study reality without using your mind, you\u2019ll understand both.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
'\u201CThe ultimate Truth is beyond words. Doctrines are words. They\u2019re not the way.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
'\u201CWhen we\u2019re deluded there\u2019s a world to escape. When we\u2019re aware, there\u2019s nothing to escape.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
'\u201CTrying to find buddha or enlightenment is like trying to grab space.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
'\u201CBe empty of worrying. Think of who created thought. Why do you stay in prison when the door is wide open? Move outside the tangle of fear-thinking. Live in silence. Flow down and down in always widening rings of being.\u201D  \u2013 Unknown',
'\u201CBeyond The Witness, there is the Infinite Intensity of Emptiness and Silence.\u201D \u2013 Sri Nisargadatta Maharaj'
];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];


}

function tweet() {
  var quote = document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML // Replace this with appopriate quote that you wanted.
  var text = quote;
  var tweet_url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + text;
  window.open(tweet_url);
};
document.getElementById("tweetButton").addEventListener("click", tweet);
```

[This is what shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5ox7.jpg)

It originally had this,

```
var text = escape(quote);
```

But would not show anything, so I put

```
var text = quote;
```

However, now I get the �.

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code here including all of the CSS.  Where is your Twitter button?  It seems you just have an image.  Have you read about Twitter intents?

Comment: I do only have an image in the HTML, in the CSS I make it "clickable."

That was why I included the CSS. 

What are Twitter intents?

Comment: Hey @KyleShive you forgot to put escape to wrap the quote.

quote  = escape(quote); See my answer again.

Comment: That way would not work and I am not 100% sure why it wasn't. However I found a way to escape it. var text = encodeURI(quote); ------------ encodeURI() worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple method that you can use to tweet the things via your twitter button.

```
function tweet() {
  var quote = document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML // Replace this with appopriate quote that you wanted.
  var text = escape(quote);
  var tweet_url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + text;
  window.open(tweet_url);
};
document.getElementById("tweetButton").addEventListener("click", tweet);
```

Comment: After I put this into the Javascript when I click on the twitter button I get this long link 

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%u201CIf%20you%20use%20your%20mind%20to%20study%20reality%2C%20you%20won%u2019t%20understand%20either%20your%20mind%20or%20reality.%20If%20you%20study%20reality%20without%20using%20your%20mind%2C%20you%u2019ll%20understand%20both.%u201D%20%u2013%20Bodhidharma

But it doesn't actually open any page up. 

And when you say, replace this with appropriate quote, how can I get it to set itself to be the current quote after it is randomly generated?

Comment: It actually works great, but right after the 

var tweet_url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + text;

I need to replace text with the current quote, everything else works great.

Comment: You need to keep the track of the randomly generated quote. Put it in some global variable or else get it directly from the DOM.

Comment: I found a way to escape it. 

  var text = encodeURI(quote);


escape(quote) is an older version and would not work, 
encodeURI() worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the function in `onclick` to call the function like a link

```js
var currentQuote = '';
var quotes = [
  '\u201CMeditation is to be aware of every thought and of every feeling, never to say it is right or wrong, but just to watch it and move with it. In that watching, you begin to understand the whole movement of thought and feeling. And out of this awareness comes silence\u201D. -  Jiddu Krishnamurti',
  '\u201CHave you not noticed that love is silence? It may be while holding the hand of another, or looking lovingly at a child, or taking in the beauty of an evening. Love has no past or future, and so it is with this extraordinary state of silence.\u201D -  Jiddu Krishnamurti',
  '\u201CA quiet mind is all you need. All else will happen rightly, once your mind is quiet. As the sun on rising makes the world active, so does self-awareness affect changes in the mind. In the light of calm and steady self-awareness, inner energies wake up and work miracles without any effort on your part.\u201D -   Nisargadatta Maharaj',
  '\u201CLet silence take you to the core of life.\u201D  \u2013 Rumi',
  '\u201CSilence is a true friend who never betrays.\u201D \u2013 Confucius',
  '\u201CYou throw thorns, falling in my silence they become flowers.\u201D \u2013 Gautama Buddha',
  '\u201CSilence is an empty space, space is the home of the awakened mind.\u201D \u2013 Gautama Buddha',
  '\u201CCare about what other people think and you will always be their prisoner.\u201D \u2013 Laozi',
  '\u201CNot thinking about anything is Zen. Once you know this, walking, sitting, or lying down, everything you do is Zen.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
  '\u201CIf you use your mind to study reality, you won\u2019t understand either your mind or reality. If you study reality without using your mind, you\u2019ll understand both.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
  '\u201CThe ultimate Truth is beyond words. Doctrines are words. They\u2019re not the way.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
  '\u201CWhen we\u2019re deluded there\u2019s a world to escape. When we\u2019re aware, there\u2019s nothing to escape.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
  '\u201CTrying to find buddha or enlightenment is like trying to grab space.\u201D \u2013 Bodhidharma',
  '\u201CBe empty of worrying. Think of who created thought. Why do you stay in prison when the door is wide open? Move outside the tangle of fear-thinking. Live in silence. Flow down and down in always widening rings of being.\u201D  \u2013 Unknown',
  '\u201CBeyond The Witness, there is the Infinite Intensity of Emptiness and Silence.\u201D \u2013 Sri Nisargadatta Maharaj'
];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];


}

function newFunction() {
  alert("Javascript Link");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'PT Serif', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  <!-- the above allows use of older browsers #D13053 -->
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 45px;
  <!-- margin-top: 100px;
  -->font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.bio {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.me {
  height: 165px;
  border-radius: 110%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.about {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.grey {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
}

.about-container {
  background: url('inc.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 2000px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: PT Serif, cursive;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: black solid 3px;
  margin-top: 85px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tweet-button {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 80px;
}

.tweet-button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.tweet-button:active {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">


  <title>Your Core</title>
</head>

<body>

  <iframe style="display: none;" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H2JtoG97zhI?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <div class="about-container">
    <div class="about">
      <img src="fib2.jpg" class="me" />


      <h1> Find the space, </h1>


      <h2>the space which is between thoughts...</h2>

      <hr class="grey" />



      <button onclick="newQuote()">Breathe and press here
       </button>


      <h3>
        <div id="quoteDisplay">
          <!-- quotes here -->
        </div>
      </h3>




      <img id="tweetButton" class="tweet-button" src="http://orig01.deviantart.net/dac8/f/2013/023/b/c/twitter_button___logo_by_pixxiepaynee-d5sfq9u.png" onclick="newFunction();">

      <script src="javascript.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```